# Why does this grid depends of unrelated variable?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to display a grid of divs with individual IDs.

I found that when the width value exceeds 10, the grid starts to create some weird patterns, some lines extend beyond the width value, some lines fold too quickly.

When I create the cell ID  using

```
cellId = x.toString() + "/" + y.toString();
```

everything seems to be ok.

What does that

```
+ "/" +
```

change? Other than simply adding string to the cellId?

I post entire code, 1) because it's short 2) to make sure the problem is not within the css.

```
<head>

    <style type = "text/css">

        .pixel {
            font-size:12px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            float:left;
            width:20px;
            height:20px;
        }


    </style>

    <script type = "text/javascript">

    </script>        

</head>

<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

   function drawBoard(height, width) {

       for (x=0; x<=height; x++) {

            for (y=0; y<=width; y++) {

                cell = document.createElement('div');  
            //    cellId = x.toString() + "/" + y.toString();
                cellId = x.toString() + y.toString();
                cell.setAttribute("id", cellId);
                document.body.appendChild(cell);
                document.getElementById(cellId).setAttribute("class", "pixel");
                if (y == 0) {
                    document.getElementById(cellId).style.clear = "both";
                    console.log(y);
                }

                document.getElementById(cellId).innerHTML = cellId;
            }

       }

   }

        drawBoard(18, 10);

    </script>


</body>
```

Comment: It just separates with `/`. Not sure what your question is here.

Comment: FYI, there's no need to do `document.getElementById(cellId)` when you can just use the `cell` variable you already made. Also, declare your variables with `var`! *(Or `let/const` for modern syntax.)*

Comment: @Krzysztof, what's the difference between `cellId = "11" + "2"` and `cellId = "1" + "12"`? and now the same exercise, including the `/`

Answer (score 6):

Your id values consist of two numbers glued together. When `x` is 8 and `y` is 32, you end up with 832. But also, when `x` is 83 and `y` is 2, you *also* end up with 832.

Your code is creating elements with duplicate id values, and that's the heart of the problem. Using the "/" character in the middle solves it. Now, in that case described above, you'd get "8/32" and "83/2".

You could use any other character besides "/" of course.

Comment: Can't this be just a comment?

Comment: @PraveenKumar why? It's the answer to the question, no?

Comment: Yea, but the question seems very low quality. Am I wrong?

Comment: @PraveenKumar well it's not the best thing ever, but I don't recall seeing this particular bug lately.

Comment: It is like what does `+` do in JavaScript. It concatenates two strings and adds two integers, duh. Something like that right?

Comment: @PraveenKumar no no, read my answer again. His question was about why the code *fails* when he *does not* include a "/" separator when he concatenates the x/y coordinates.

Comment: Praveen you don't understand the problem. The question incorrectly assumes the string operation is doing something special, which you are focusing on, but there is a real bug here causing a real issue.